# Repair corrupted directory files

Tags: windows-xp, filesystem-corruption

Last time I used my computer, it ran out of battery and turned off while I was working.
Now when I restart it and try to start my web browser, it reports that files were corrupted.
I cannot reinstall the browser or delete any of the corrupted folders.

I have also tried the Windows `CHKDISK` utility, but it fails to run or fix the errors.

Is there any possible way to repair corrupted files and directories?

Comment: Which web browser are you using?

Comment: It's `chkdsk` :) What did it say when it failed to run?

Comment: Firefox and opera both refused to start with `error: ApplicationData/Opera/` corrupted. I couldn't delete the directories either.

Comment: @techie007: I ran chkdsk on C:\ from `right click > properties > tools > check now` it fails at phase 1 with `error: couldn't complete operation.`

Comment: What was the _exact_ error it gave you?  What does chkdsk do when you run it in [Safe Mode](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/boot_failsafe.mspx?mfr=true), or from the [Recovery Console](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314058)?